# Integral of $\sin(x^2)/x^2$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, lebesgue-integral

So I was wondering if  $\int_{0}^{\infty}\sin(x^2)/x^2$is finite. My intuition is to say yes but I'm not so sure also I have no idea how to calculate the integral, so I'm looking for some tips. By the way I'm working with the Lebesgue integral.

Comment: Just for your own interest, it evaluates to $\sqrt{\pi/2}$

Comment: you need d(something) for integral to make sense.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that $\sin(x^2) < x^2$, so the integral from $0$ to $1$ is finite. Also note that the absolute value of $\frac{\sin(x^2)}{x^2}$ is at most $\frac{1}{x^2}$, the integral of which converges for $x$ from $1$ to $\infty$. So the integral is finite.